# Finding mean of range of age

Tags: correlation

Please could you show me how to find mean age of 54 participants, out of these 15 males and 39 females (their ages ranging between 18 to 33). Please find:
1) mean of 54 participants
2) mean of 15 males
3) mean of 39 
Please also show to work it out so I could try it at home.
Thanks

Comment: Just curious, is this a college homework problem or a 5th grade homework problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the answer to your three questions we would need the actual ages of the 54 participants. With the ages:

- mean of 54 participants = sum of participant ages / 54
- mean of 15 males= sum of male ages / 15
- mean of 39 females = sum of female ages / 39